# how to create canvas boundary limit which scales when zoomed? (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've read a few posts regarding this subject but I'm yet to crack the solution for my particular problem.

Here is a plnk;

http://plnkr.co/edit/ScJGKwR74H8UjsaJqfZF?p=preview

The aim here is that you are able to zoom into the image, but the image remains visible inside the canvas at all times with no white space when dragged. The problem is really happening within this part of the code;

```
  obj = e.target;

  obj.setCoords();

  var boundingRect = obj.getBoundingRect();
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  var viewportMatrix = canvas.viewportTransform;

  boundingRect.top = (boundingRect.top - viewportMatrix[5]) / zoom;
  boundingRect.left = (boundingRect.left - viewportMatrix[4]) / zoom;
  boundingRect.width /= zoom;
  boundingRect.height /= zoom;

  var pHeight = obj.canvas.height * zoom,
      pWidth = obj.canvas.width * zoom,
      nHeight = obj.canvas.height - pHeight,
      nWidth = obj.canvas.width - pWidth;

  // top-left  corner
  if (boundingRect.top < nHeight || boundingRect.left < nWidth) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, nHeight + obj.top - boundingRect.top);
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, nWidth + obj.left - boundingRect.left);
  }
```

When I click the zoom button, I want to have a negative number output as I want the image to be dragged off screen but never leave any white space. I have it half-working, but I'm not sure how to get it so the boundary limit will always be calculated to the scaled version of the image?

Hope someone can point out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried refactoring the logic on the top-left corner slightly so that it uses the bottom right corner for preventing it from going out of the canvas in either direction.  It looks like:

```
  var canvasHeight = obj.canvas.height / zoom,
    canvasWidth = obj.canvas.width / zoom,
    rTop = boundingRect.top + boundingRect.height,
    rLeft = boundingRect.left + boundingRect.width;

  // Where top left corner check used to be
  if (rTop < canvasHeight || rLeft < canvasWidth) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, canvasHeight - boundingRect.height);
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, canvasWidth - boundingRect.width);
  }
```

Basically, instead of checking to see if the top of the image has gone past the difference in the size of the canvas, it checks to see if the bottom of the image has come off of the bottom of the zoomed in canvas.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cjAWEqrdnL6skKQYsFM2?p=preview

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer, there is a problem when trying to set the boundary with a grouped object? I've had a couple attempts at trying to sort it but no luck, if you could take a look? [Plunk 1 (top/left corner working, bottom/right not)](http://plnkr.co/edit/hszOjx2ZlaUl82e6dIRH?p=preview), and [Plunk 2 (nothing is working, but could potentially be fixed?)](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCz9XqgLc6QXkl6qOVtF?p=preview)

Comment: Hi (again), I've got it to kind of work but it isn't very reliable as it leaves white space when zoomed in at a greater scale, [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hszOjx2ZlaUl82e6dIRH?p=preview).

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by what you're doing.  The logic is the same for an object or a group of objects; if you just substitute in a group within the listener, everything should function the same.  I think that some of the stuff you are doing with adding the rectangle to the canvas and then manually controlling the group are mucking things up.